Is it possible to get In-app purchase reports in Sandbox account via the App Store Connect API?
I'm implementing in app purchase/subscriptions for my application and would like to setup a financial report module in my admin portal. I am bit confused, is it possible to get financial reports and invoices via the API when in sandbox account. Also I would greatly appreciate it if you could also share the API and parameters needed, by which we can get the finance reports and invoices.
Thank You in advance.

AFAIK, you can, however, you need an Apple Developer Program account to set up In-App Purchase, i.e, subscription offers. Then you're able to get the transactions.

@sonle Could you provide the API document that refers to this?

This following page describes testing In-app purchases with sandbox.
You can make a request to get the purchase history by:

https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt

Notice: You may get multiple transactions in a short amount of time because by default, the auto-renew subscription on the sandbox environment will perform every 5 minutes.
